# Android: TextInputLayout stacking on eachother

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to implement TextInputLayout to my layout. I have 3 EditText's. I am wrapping each one within an individual TextInputLayout.

Instead of seperating, they are stacking on top of eachother.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_colour">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_form_relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/username_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_unread"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_unread"
                android:hint="@string/sign_in_username_field"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/username_input_layout"
                android:background="@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_secure_dark"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_secure_dark"
                android:hint="@string/reg_password"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/server_api_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_api_url"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/password_input_layout"
                android:background="@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_private_server"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_private_server"
                android:hint="@string/sign_in_server_field"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textUri"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/server_api_layout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_normal_to_bright"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/reg_sign_in"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_forgot_pwd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/reg_forgot_password"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/flavor_hyperlink_text_colour"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Please assist.

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is and what you're trying to achieve. Could you please post the screenshot of the app and explain what is wrong with it?

Comment: There are 3 Text Edits. Username, Password, and Server. When applying the TextInputLayouts, as indicated, they stack on top of eachother. I will update the question with what is happening. I need to know what I am doing wrong that is resulting in them stacking.

Comment: I have added the screen shots

Comment: use LinearLayout instead vertical as parent and horizontal for image and text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have the `android:layout_below="@+id/username_input_layout"` on your `EditText`with ID: `android:id="@+id/sign_in_password"`

Instead you should have it on your `TextInputLayout` with ID: `android:id="@+id/password_input_layout"` like so:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/username_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_unread"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_unread"
            android:hint="@string/sign_in_username_field"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android.layou_below="@+id/username_input_layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_secure_dark"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_secure_dark"
            android:hint="@string/reg_password"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/server_api_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android.layou_below="@+id/password_input_layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_api_url"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_private_server"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_private_server"
            android:hint="@string/sign_in_server_field"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textUri"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This is the way to use `layout_below`

```
container1
    editText
container below container1
    editText
```

You try to do this:

```
container
    editText
container
    editText below container1
```

Try this and please report back your progress

Comment: The TextInputLayout isn't working on the 2nd and 3rd EditText. Only the 1st one

Comment: The edittext's display, but the TextInputLayout Wrapping isn't working. The hint on shows on the first EditText, second and third dont

Comment: Hmm. Could you attach an image of that?

Comment: Nevermind, it is working, but there are other issues not related to this question. I will post the questions when I give up on trying to solve them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If by stacking you mean that the `TextInputLayouts` overlay each other, then this probably happens because you're using a `RelativeLayout`. If you want those to appear one below the other, than either switch to a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation` set to `vertical`, or use the `android:layout_below` attribute to specify correct relations betweens the views.